Horror movie with group of researchers came to a haunted house
I'm looking for a movie where action of the movie was: 
A group of researchers came to a haunted house, house had large metal gates fastened with a chain and padlock, was a group of about six people who entered and stayed there. On the floor was  some kind of equipment that have a lever that pulls and appear a man who was naked and was red like blood, witch transforms in to a monster and kill the all people. Only one escape. I remember the name, it was Tom, at the end of the movie, he jumps from the buildings and die. After he saw in a mirror that he have a small hole in his forehead from which a snake came out. I want to know what it is called, I'm looking for a few years.

You may be looking for the movie From Beyond 1986
It features key scenes that you mention in your question such as the snake like creature coming out of his forehead and a character pulling a lever to activate a device aka The Resonator.
The monster is also red/ pink as described.
The machine that is turned on is designed to stimulate the Pineal Gland. In this movie the "snake" is actually the Gland itself protruding out of the forehead.
The machine experiment produces the following result:

An unforeseen result of their experiments is the ability to perceive creatures from another dimension that proceed to drag the head scientist into their world, returning him as a grotesque shape-changing monster that preys upon the others at the laboratory.

Here is the trailer:




You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

@NapoleonWilson - Apologies I just needed a few minutes to add some detail. I wanted to post the answer before anyone else did :)

You don't say...

This is a pretty good guess. IIRC all the males die (Crawford sacrificing himself to stop the bad guy) and Barbara Crampton is put into an ambulance AFTER jumping from the attic window, muttering "but he ATE him...." over and over. Another memorable scene in this film are swarms of insects that are attracted to light, one character is trapped in the beam of a flashlight and is consumed.

Thanks for the helpful comment & extra info. I've only seen parts of the film & that was years ago, but most of it matched up so I took a shot. I know there's no character called Tom, but the female jumping from the window definitely gives it a bit more hope. Cheers @JasonK
